# Index out of bounds Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, octave

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from math import *
import numpy as np

#parameters
n= 101
delx= 0.5
delt=0.1
D=1.0

alpha=D*delt/(delx*delx)

#initial profile
a=np.zeros(n)
a[0]=1.0

#loop for time and x
 for j in range(0,500):
  for i in range(1,101):
   a[i]=a[i]*(1-2*alpha)+alpha*(a[i-1]+a[i+1]) 
   a[100]=a[i]*(1-2*alpha)+2*alpha*(a[i-1])   

#loop for 20 figures
for j in range(20):
plt.plot(a,'r-')
plt.show()
```

I'm getting `Index out of bounds error`. I'm new to python, pls explain and fix. (Originally code in Octave), so having issues for doing it in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `i` reaches 100 in the inner loop (BTW, I have doubts about whether you need the outer loop at all), `a[i+1]` will try to access `a[101]`, which doesn't exist.

Also, the last loop, given the current indentation will plot 20 copies of the same data, which is probably not what you need.

Comment: It was for  a[i]=a[i]*(1-2*alpha)+alpha*(a[i-1]+a[i+1])

Comment: @Ganesh, that `a[i+1]` at the very end of this line causes the problem.

Comment: @Ganesh, I don't know what you're trying to plot. Do you want to do the plotting after each iteration of the inner loop? Or the outer one? Or what? I think you'd better re-read the Octave code and see what it's doing before attempting to translate it to Python.

Comment: Then there'd be 100 * 500 = 50000 lines on a single graph. Is this what you want? If yes, get rid of everything after the `#loop for 20 figures` comment, except `plt.show()` and move `plt.plot(a)` inside the inner loop.

Comment: But where do you get these time steps from? Your current code doesn't seem to have any concept of a time step at all. And if you want to plot for each iteration of the inner loop, you'll get half a million plots on the same graph, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
for j in range(0,500):
 for i in range(1,101):
  a[i]=a[i]*(1-2*alpha)+alpha*(a[i-1]+a[i+1]) 
   a[100]=a[i]*(1-2*alpha)+2*alpha*(a[i-1])
```

when `i` is `100`, you access to `a[i+1]` which is `a[101]`, but a can only be indexed `0` through `100` (size is `n=101`)

Answer (score 0):

When you change n= 101 to n= 102 your code works correctly.